# How can I make an api call dynamic with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks

How can I use the value from the input form and only make an api call when the button is submitted?
Right now when I press submit I am receiving back the user name which is what I expect and want to receive, however it doesn't seem to be sending the information back to userCard. I realize right now I'm not calling it in the form but I'm a bit unsure how to approach this one.

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Form, Button} from "react-bootstrap"
import axios from "axios";
import UserCard from "./Card";



const UserForm = () => {

    const[user, setUser] = useState("");
    const[login, setLogin] =  useState("");
  const handleChange = (e) =>{
        //console.log(e.target.value)
        setUser(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        //e.preventDefault();
        console.log("Button was submitted",user);
        axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
        .then((res => 
            {setLogin(res.data);
         
            })
        )
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    return (
        
        <div className = "Form">
        <Form  onSubmit={handleSubmit} onChange = {handleChange} spellcheck="false" >
       <Form.Group controlId="formName">
            <Form.Label> Github Handle </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter Handle Here" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button onClick = {handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
        
        </Form>

        </div>
    )
}

export default UserForm;
```

```
import React from "react"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom"
import UserForm from "./UserForm"

const UserCard = (props) =>{
        return(
         <div className = "Card">
            <UserForm /> 
            <h1>Hello, {props.login}</h1>
            <h2>How is the weather in {props.location}?</h2>
            <h3>Here's a little about you </h3>
            <p>{props.bio}</p>
            <nav>
            <ul className = "cardlist">
            <li><NavLink to = "/followers" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Go To Followers</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to = "/repos" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Go To Repos</NavLink> </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }

export default UserCard;
```

```
import './App.css';
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import UserCard from "./components/Card";
import Followers from "./components/Followers";
import Repos from "./components/Repos";
import UserForm from "./components/UserForm"

let followerArray = [];

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    user: '' ,
    location : '',
    bio: '',
    followers: [],
    repos: []

  }
   
  //make api calls after the component mounts --> equivalent to useEffect()
  //componentDidUpdate is equivalent to useEffect(,[])
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Component mounted");
    //get user data
   
        console.log("finished")

        //get repos
       
  }

  render()
  {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
            <Route exact path = "/">
          <UserCard  name = {this.state.name} 
          login = {this.state.user} 
          location = {this.state.location} 
          bio = {this.state.bio}
          />
    </Route>
    <Route path = "/followers"  followers ={this.state.followers}>
    <Followers />
    </Route>
    <Route path = "/repos">
    <Repos repos={this.state.repos}/>
    </Route>
    </div>
    
    </BrowserRouter>
    

  );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you wanting to pass the `login` "state" to the `UserCard` component, wherever it's being rendered? Can you share a more comprehensive code example showing how and where you render both these components? As far as I can tell, your API call is already dynamic since it uses the current `user` state value when making the GET request.

Comment: You probably also want to keep the `e.preventDefault();` in the form's submit handler so the default form action isn't taken and reloads the page/app.

Comment: Yes exactly, I want the login user name to be passed to Usercard. I'm rendering it in App and I've edited code. I know this is wrong but when I'm not sure how to approach.

Comment: I will uncomment that piece. Thank you

Comment: Ok, Danial's answer below is what I'd suggest... lifting the state into the parent component and passing down state and callbacks as props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to get back some values from child component, you can pass a function to child component. In your case:

1. Define a Callback `function` in `UserCard` component and use the callback function data in card:

```
import React from "react"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom"
import UserForm from "./UserForm"

const UserCard = (props) =>{
    const[user, setUser] = useState("");
    const[login, setLogin] =  useState("");
    const giveBackDataToCard = (login , user) => {
       setLogin(login);
       setUser(user);
    }

        return(
         <div className = "Card">
            <UserForm /> 
            <h1>Hello, {login}</h1>
            <h2>How is the weather in {user.location}?</h2>
            <h3>Here's a little about you </h3>
            <p>{user.bio}</p>
            <nav>
            <ul className = "cardlist">
            <li><NavLink to = "/followers" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Go To Followers</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to = "/repos" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>Go To Repos</NavLink> </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
            </div>
        )
    }

export default UserCard;
```

2. Call props function where you want:

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {Form, Button} from "react-bootstrap"
import axios from "axios";
import UserCard from "./Card";

const UserForm = () => {

    
    const handleChange = (e) =>{
        setUser(e.target.value);
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
        .then((res => 
            {
                setLogin(res.data);
//------------> For example here
                props.giveBackDataToCard(res.data,e.target.value);

            })
        )
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    return (
        
        <div className = "Form">
        <Form  onSubmit={handleSubmit} onChange={handleChange} spellcheck="false" >
       <Form.Group controlId="formName">
            <Form.Label> Github Handle </Form.Label>
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Enter Handle Here" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button onClick = {handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
        
        </Form>

        </div>
    )
}

export default UserForm;
```

Comment: This definitely helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, If your question is if you want send back the data to the userCard from userForm, You should follow these methods.
**First method is**, You should learn first a Context APIs in react which already mentioned in docs https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html , use it for passing data between a screen.
**Second method is**, Always call the API at parent level component, I think its a better and easier way. By calling API from parent level component you will have to pass some props to according to your useForm required.
**Third method is,** The best way to use some state management store, like [Mobx](https://mobx.js.org/README.html), [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) etc... It is a best way. You can then actually pass your state dynamically to your useCard component.

If answer matched you question, that  will great, If not tell so that I will delete for community help.